# Aspose PDF : Is it possible to make an object 'non printable'?

Tags: java, pdf, aspose

Do you know if it is possible to make an object 'non printable' <=> make it so that object will not be printed along with all the other objects of the page ?

For example I would like to display a TextAnnotation, a Rectangle, an Image and a TextFragment on a PDF page, but not print them.

Is there a way to do that ? By setting a nonPrintable property or by locking those items ?

Thanks,

Comment: First of all, PDF is all about "what you see is what you print".  Secondly, it IS possible, but it looks like Aspose doesn't support Optional Content Groups (OCGs).

Comment: I believe you can toggle annotation visibility in Javascript, and Aspose supports generating acrobat's JS DOM.  I believe there are document-level "will print" and "did print" events you can hook into to flip things off and on.  Not terribly secure though.  Anyone with Acrobat could remove your script.

Comment: @Astyan, there is no such specific property to make objects non-printable in Aspose.PDF. However, we will surely investigate the feasibility of your requirements. Could you please share a sample PDF document by uploading it to Google Drive or Dropbox. This is Asad Ali and I work at Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: Thanks for the comments ! 
I have shared an example here : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1sLr_LhYg3O0gXAcWqyEjIyWF3DphBg5A . The A/C image displays more information with a tooltip and an annotation.

The goal is to generate only one pdf, which could be :
- read interactively on a computer with some annotations / tooltips that provide more information
- printed without these annotations / tooltips

Maybe I can do this differently : as an annotation is not printed, is it possible to give an annotation a rectangle form with a specific color and text ?